# Ant Design Table: Reset table search/filter/sort to default multiple sort

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am using Ant Design's Table (v4.xx), with multiple columns that have a combination of filter, sort or search.

By default, it will have multiple sort of 2 specific columns.

I want to create a button to reset all filters/search/sort to the default multiple sort of 2 specific columns.

Tried to use sortOrder but it only allows for one column.

Current column props:

```js
<Table
  columns={[
    {
      dataIndex: "table_name",
      defaultSortOrder: "ascend",
      filterSearch: true,
      filters: [...someValues],
      sorter: {
        multiple: 2,
        compare: (a, b) => a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : 0
      }
    },
    {
      dataIndex: "table_description",
      filterDropdown: ...someFunc,
      filteredValue: null,
    },
    {
      dataIndex: "column_name",
      defaultSortOrder: "ascend",
      filterSearch: true,
      filters: [...someValues],
      sorter: {
        multiple: 1,
        compare: (a, b) => a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : 0
      }
    },
    ...moreCols,
    {
      dataIndex: "length",
      filterDropdown: ...someFunc,
      filteredValue: null,
      sorter: {
        compare: (a, b) => parseInt(a) - parseInt(b)
      }
    }
  ]}
/>
```

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: Please post also some of your code(s).

Comment: @Newbee added the column props